# Converting char in string to unsigned long long in C++

Tags: c++, hex

Okay, so I was working on building a Base64 encoder/decoder that converts hexadecimal to base64 and back but I found a weird issue that I'm trying to understand, here's the code:

```
string b64_encode(string str)
{
    string newStr = "";
    string ref = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    unsigned long long h = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i+=3)
    {
        //Get every 3 chars
        char a = str[i];
        char b = str[i+1];
        char c = str[i+2];

        //Now, convert each hex character (base 16) to it's equivalent decimal number
        //and merge them into one variable
        h = strtoull(&a, nullptr, 16) << 8; //shift left by 8 bits
        h |= strtoull(&b, nullptr, 16) << 4; //shift left by 4 bits
        h |= strtoull(&c, nullptr, 16); //no shift required only the first 2 characters need

        cout << h << endl; //for testing purposes only
    }

    return newStr;
}
```

When I run this code on Mac OSX, I get the following result, which is incorrect:

```
4052
3959
1570
4091
3814
...
```

However, I wrote the same code on Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 8, it gives me the correct values:

```
1170
1901
518
2921
1734
...
```

Hexadecimal string that I used:

```
string str = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
```

So my question is that is there any way to display the right numbers on Mac OSX as well? I looked up for it online but it didn't help much.

Comment: `&a` is not a 0-terminated string, so you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch if that's the case, how does it work on Windows ?

Comment: It seems related mac endianess

Comment: @MegaColorBoy Undefined behaviour implies that anything can happen, it can even appear as if it works correctly.

Comment: @Johan Yeap, I understand that but my question is, do you have any idea how this could be resolved? or Is there any difference in bit architecture?because my Mac is 64bit whereas my Windows is 32bit

Comment: You can fix the undefined behaviour, so it will not work by luck anymore: https://ideone.com/LxmwW3 or with your sample input: https://ideone.com/2GMMJX

Comment: @MegaColorBoy Personally I would not use strtoull to convert a single hex-digit to a number. I would use something like `(ch > '9' ? ( 10 + (ch - 'a')) : (ch - '0'))`, assuming that I know that the input has been checked.

Comment: @mch you're a genius !! :D

Comment: It's abound endianness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to @mch, the issue was that the characters were not 0-terminated, which invoked undefined behavior, thanks to him, this issue is fixed:

```
string b64_encode(string str)
{
    string newStr = "";
    string ref = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    unsigned long long h = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i+=3)
    {
        //Get every 3 chars
        char a[2] = {str[i], 0};
        char b[2] = {str[i+1], 0};
        char c[2] = {str[i+2], 0};

        //Now, convert each hex character (base 16) to it's equivalent decimal number
        //and merge them into one variable
        h = strtoull(a, nullptr, 16) << 8; //shift left by 8 bits
        h |= strtoull(b, nullptr, 16) << 4; //shift left by 4 bits
        h |= strtoull(c, nullptr, 16); //no shift required only the first 2 characters need

        cout << h << endl;
    }

    return newStr;
}
```